# commandline for adding trusted intranet site to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, trusted-sites

I'm running a batch from a network share. The batch is opening a new batch, and then I get a security warning. I want to remove this so I don't need to push "run" all the time. I tested it manually by entering the server IP to *Trusted Sites on intranet* in IE. Is there a command I can inject to my batch making my computer add this automatically?

Answer (score 3):

(Answered by the OP in edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> 1. Made a regfile:
>
> `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\192.168.1.241] "*"=dword:00000001"`
>
> 2. Made a batchfile:
>
> `regedit -s addtrust.reg`
>
> **WARNING:** Editing the registry is quite dangerous, and shouldn't be used to do this, though it may be the only way.